# quarkus jaxrs non-blocking misconception

Tags: java, jax-rs, vert.x, quarkus

As far I've been able reading:

- [this quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#quarkus-http), quarkus is using worker threads in order perform jaxrs endpoints.
- [this vert.x documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#worker_verticles), worker threads are designed for calling **blocking code**.

Probably misconceptions: what exactly do following terms mean?

- Server non-blocking code.
- Server asynchronous response processing.
- Server reactive code.

My question is: why ain't I able to create non-blocking code using jax-rs endpoints and leverage standard event-loop thread?

**EDIT**:

A couple of question are strugling my mind:

> Resteasy is not async by default, but it is capable of handling non blocking async response

1. Which is the difference between `async by default`, and `is capable of handling non blocking async response`?
2. From here, I figure out any JAX-RS implementation is able to handle non blocking async response, since `@Suspended` is a JAX-RS annotation, doesn't it?

I think [this article](http://www.programmr.com/blogs/difference-between-asynchronous-and-non-blocking) explains very well what those concepts are meant for.

**EDIT 2**:

By other side, according to [Quarkus Http documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#quarkus-http), it says:

> All the HTTP requests your application receive are handled by event loops (IO Thread) and then are routed towards the code that manages the request. **Depending on the destination, it can invoke the code managing the request on a worker thread (Servlet, Jax-RS) or use the IO Thread (reactive route)**.

Form here, I figure out that, by default, all JAX-RS "endpoints" are handled by a **worker thread (worker verticle?)** since they are blocking by default.

According to vert.x documentation:

> By default blocking code is executed on the Vert.x worker pool.

My questions now are:

3. As we have mentioned before, we are able to make a jax-rs "endpoint" non-blocking using an `AsyncResponse`. Is it mandatory to use a worker thread when the jax-rs endpoint in to a blocking code now?
4. a "quarkus worker thread" is equivalent to "vert.x worker verticle"?

Comment: 3) If you're a concurrency expert - then no, it's not mandatory. Otherwise, it's much safer to use worker threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAX-RS is just a standard. Quarkus uses RESTEasy as JAX-RS implementation. RESTEasy uses blocking API:

> Resteasy is not async by default, but it is capable of handling non
>   blocking async response, specially with Vert.x

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/resteasy-examples

RESTEasy is part of JBoss. JBoss is part of Red Hat. Quarkus is also a Red Hat Project.

Theoretically, you could use another JAX-RS implementation that is non blocking. But then I'm not aware of any, for one simple reason - JAX-RS is quite outdated.

Things like `async by default` may mean a lot of different things. In terms of Vert.x, it means that most of the APIs are either expect a callback or return some kind of Future (`Deferred value`, if you please).

Having established that, `is capable of handling non blocking async response` means that by default, JAX-RS blocks until the value is returned, but technically, it's possible to wrap this in a kind of `deferred value` too. That's what Vert.x RestEasy integration does.

`@Suspended`, or more specifically, `AsyncResponse`, is another way to wrap those values, although much hackier one than some others.

Comment: I added some more explanation on the topic.

Comment: Why do you say "JAX-RS is quite outdated"?

Comment: It's a standard released in '06.

Comment: Are you using any other standard alternative?

Comment: We're using standard Vert.x router

Comment: How do you get things like OpenAPI? Is there any repository over there providing any helping code?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I don't understand the "JAX-RS is old because it's from 2006" bit. It's a specification like any other in the JavaEE platform and gets updated on a schedule. The CDI spec was formalized in 2011; do you consider that outdated?